# How to reduce image size in java

Tags: java, image

**(NOTE: I can not use any library which directly resize the image, I want to know the core logic  of resizing )**

I have an  grayscale image  with  dimensions 256*256 . I want to  modify it and create  following three images
 a) image with  dimensions 128*128
 b) image with dimensions 64*64
 c) image with dimensions 32*32.

pseudo code

```
File fi = new File("E:\\input.raw");
byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());

File fo= new File("E:\\output.raw");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fo);

int i=0;
  for(;i<fileContent.length;i++){
  //dividing by 2 to create image with dimensions 128*128
  fileContent[i]= (byte) ((fileContent[i])/2);
    stream.write(fileContent[i]);
  }
    stream.close();
```

Above Code does not work.It is creating image with  256*256  dimensions.
 Due to some reasons I am not allowed to use any library that directly  reduces the dimensions. I want to know how can I convert  256*256 image to  128*128 dimensions ?

Comment: "Due to some reasons". You mean this is some sort of interview or homework question. While homework questions are allowed here, you need to show your work first. You haven't written basically anything. If this is an interview question, you're not a very good fit for the place.

Comment: @Kayaman I have added code snippet of my work in question.

Comment: Why would you think dividing the byte values somehow affects the *size* of the image? That doesn't make sense in any way.

Comment: just a side note - if you want to resize from 256x256 to 128x128 you'll have to divide by 4 (hence you'^re taking of squares and thus need to divide by  sq(2)=4)

Comment: You basically take one pixel (e.g. the top left) from each square of 4 pixels. For better results filter the original image first to remove high frequency content.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help

```
/**
 * scale image
 * 
 * @param sbi image to scale
 * @param imageType type of image
 * @param dWidth width of destination image
 * @param dHeight height of destination image
 * @param fWidth x-factor for transformation / scaling
 * @param fHeight y-factor for transformation / scaling
 * @return scaled image
 */
public static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage sbi, int imageType, int dWidth, int dHeight, double fWidth, double fHeight) {
    BufferedImage dbi = null;
    if(sbi != null) {
        dbi = new BufferedImage(dWidth, dHeight, imageType);
        Graphics2D g = dbi.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(fWidth, fHeight);
        g.drawRenderedImage(sbi, at);
    }
    return dbi;
}
```

Comment: *"I am not allowed to use any library that directly reduces the dimensions."*

Comment: Well he/she can always check inside the libraries, see how it works and write it himself/herself

Answer (score -1):

Using [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) and [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) it can be done as follows

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\image\\test.jpg"));
int[] dims = {128, 64, 32};

for(int dim : dims) {
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(dim, dim, type);
    Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, dim, dim, null);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", new File("c:\\image\\test_" + dim + "x" + dim + ".jpg"));
}
```

Comment: *"I am not allowed to use any library that directly reduces the dimensions."*

Comment: [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) and [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) are java internal libraries not external

Comment: Please re-read my quote - it does not refer to **external libraries** but libraries that **directly reduce the dimensions**. It is obvious that the OP was tasked with a rather academic request just to show he can solve the problem. The OP even edited his post to specifically point this out.

Comment: check image processing [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#Algorithms) then